# How do I logout a user from IPB externally?

Tags: php, single-sign-on, ipb, invision-power-board

I have built a `SSO (Single Sign-On)` system for use between our main site and the `Invision Power Board` software but I'm not sure how to go about logging the user out of `IPB` when they log out from the main site?

Additionally, what files would I need to load in the external file to be able to do this?

Comment: Are they hosted on the same domain?

Comment: @Companjo Yes, the forum is @ `/forum/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: to use IPB code for this, you have to include

`require_once( IPS_ROOT_PATH . 'applications/core/modules_public/global/login.php' );`

then to extend `public_core_global_login` and to call it's `doLogout()` method
for this to work you have to set `$this->member->setMember( $member_id );`
I, personally, have never done it this way, so bellow is how you can do it manually:

IPB sets the data in session and stores several cookies for auto-login. You can perform without using any IPB sources; what you have to do is (note query and updatecookie are some pseudofunctions, for performing DB queries and setting cookie values respectively):

```
  query("DELETE FROM ".$ibf_prefix."sessions WHERE member_id = $userid");

  updatecookie($ibf_cookieid."member_id",0,time()-1800);
  updatecookie($ibf_cookieid."pass_hash",0,time()-1800);
  updatecookie($ibf_cookieid."session_id",0,time()-1800);
```

You can read $ibf_prefix from conf_global.php :

```
$ibf_prefix = $INFO[sql_tbl_prefix];
```

and `$ibf_cookieid` is:

```
$ibf_cache = query_first("SELECT cs_value FROM " . $ibf_prefix . "cache_store WHERE cs_key = 'settings'");
$ibf_cache = unserialize($ibf_cache['cs_value']);

$ibf_cookieid = $ibf_cache['cookie_id'];
```

You can read the source of `doLogout` method in `admin/applications/core/modules_public/global/login.php`

I'm not aware of any IPB API for this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. I will have to give it a try. So will I need to include `conf_global.php` as well as `login.php`? And if I do it manually, do I still need to include `login.php`? Lastly, I thought I would need to load some kind of init file - I think the file for IPB is `initdata.php` ?

Comment: If you do it manually, you don't need anything else than the conf_global.php. If you do it by extending the login, I believe you have to include initdata.php, sources/base/ipsRegistry.php and sources/base/ipsController.php, but as I said I never done it before

Comment: I just got around to trying this...... wondering what does `query_first` do and how does it return an array of data?

Comment: @Brett something like:
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if ($result) {
   return mysql_fetch_array($result);
}

Answer (score 0):

You can try to destroy the session with `session_destroy();`

If the user has "Remember me" checked, you have to delete the cookie `pass_hash` too.

Comment: That solution seems a bit ad-hoc, would prefer to use the same method IPB does to log the user out itself.